# Terminate function execution using confirm()

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Using the `confirm()` method, how can you stop function execution after a `FALSE` return WITHOUT a conditional? Here is an example call and an abbreviated function:

```
<form>
    <input value="Play" type="button" onClick="LetsPlay();">
</form> 

function LetsPlay()
{

    confirm("Request permission to play Abracadabra!");
    prompt("Pick a number between 10 and 20");
    //more actions to follow
}
```

Comment: Okay, now that the question's answered, WHY do you need to do this? :)

Comment: Co-worker challenge....in the real world, I would always use a conditional!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [short-circuit logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and an [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

```
function LetsPlay()
{

    confirm("Request permission to play Abracadabra!") && (function () {
        prompt("Pick a number between 10 and 20");
        //more actions to follow
    })();
}
```

If the confirm function returns false, it doesn't bother to evaluate the expression following `&&` (short-circuit logic).

It's easier to read the program if you put the inner function by itself.

```
function LetsPlay()
{
    confirm("Request permission to play Abracadabra!") && StartPlay();
}

function StartPlay() {
    prompt("Pick a number between 10 and 20");
    //more actions to follow
}
```